# Flight connection at Abu Dhabi Airport (AUH)

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, uae, abu-dhabi

I am holder of passport of Uzbekistan. I plan to fly via Abu Dhabi airport (AUH). Two flights are served by the same airline - Wizz Air Abu Dhabi. I am flying without checked baggage, so I do not need to recheck it at AUH.
The first flight arrives to Abu Dhabi at 01:10 AM, the second flight departs from Abu Dhabi at 22:10 PM (the same day). Time between flights is 21 hours. I have these questions:

1. Is it possible to transfer without crossing border (passport check) from the first gate to another gate? If yes, do I need to get transit visa in this case?
2. Can I get free 48h transit visa to visit Abu Dhabi or Dubai? I found that passengers of UAE flag carrier airlines (e.g. Emirates) can get free 48h transit visa, but I could not find information for Wizz Air Abu Dhabi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you want to do transit without a visa, you **will** need to have booked a room at a hotel that is airside of the airport because your stay is greater to 12h (list on [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/abu-dhabi-airport-guide.htm#hotels))

According to TIMATIC (database used by airlines to check documentation needs) :

> Passport
> Admission and Transit Restrictions:
> Passengers are not allowed to transit through Abu Dhabi (AUH) for more than 24 hours. Passengers must have a confirmed airside hotel booking if their transit time exceeds 12 hours.
> Visa
> Visa required.
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
> Health
> Vaccinations not required.

2. Yes, you can apply for such a visa on [Ethiad's website](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/visas)

Ethiad states :

> This facility is open for Guests visiting the UAE travelling on Etihad Airways and Partner Airlines, and also to Guests with valid tickets issued by any Airlines and fulfilling the eligibility conditions announced from time to time by the UAE Authorities.